# DIY Installing a sliding patio door -not sure about the clearance I need around the door

Tags: doors, patio

It seems that my existing vinyl patio door is near standard but not quite there
Here are the dimensions:
H 81"
W 69 3/8"
D 5 3/8"

On the lateral sides I have room as follows
-left side 1.5" (the long stripes of plywood 1" and 0.5" sandwich-ed)
-right side 1" of plywood
These were used to fill in the gap 
I am not sure if there is any more wood on the perimeter of the door opening

**I am planning to buy one of these doors. Is it a good replacement?**
**Do I have enough clearance to install it ?**
https://www.homedepot.ca/product/stanley-doors-72-inch-x-80-inch-clear-lowe-argon-prefinished-white-left-hand-vinyl-sliding-patio-door-energy-star-/1000846301

As you can see it is 72x80 (70.75 x 79.50")
The depth is 4.63"

Here is a picture of the top left corner
[image]

Comment: Are you sure a 72x82 wouldn't fit? Seems like the 72x80 would leave you with a large gap at the top to be filled.

Comment: It might fit. I need ro look under that top board you can guess in the picture. I am more worried about the sides

Comment: there is room above, it is all filled with wood